# Bug XSecurity on Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to install the [XSecurity](https://github.com/XSecurity/XSecurity) plugin on Xcode 5.1. and followed the steps mentioned documentation.

The bug I found is on this step :

> "Real-time Vulnerability Notifications Activate it from the menu 'XSecurity > Vulnerability Notifications > Activate'"

When I do it, XCode just crashes...

Is anyone got the same problem or a solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this. I reloaded xcode and Xsecurity and now it is not crashing. Not sure if the easiest resolution, but worked.